# Variance and covariance matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, normal-distribution, covariance, variance

Let $(X,Y)$ ~ $N\left(\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}\right.$,$\left.\begin{bmatrix}7 & 2\\2 & 3\end{bmatrix}\right)$ . Find distribution of $T = 3X + 4Y$.

I know if $X$ ~ $N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and $Z = AX$ then $Z$ ~ $N(A\mu, A\Sigma A^T)$

I think that the $A$ is something like $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$, then the $\mu = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}18\end{bmatrix}$

but I got a problem to find $\Sigma$ for $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking about finding $\mu_T$ is okay.

Finding "covariance matrix" $\Sigma$ is a matter of calculating:

$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 4\end{array}\right]$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
7 & 2\\
2 & 3
\end{array}\right]$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
3\\
4
\end{array}\right]$

resulting in a $1\times 1$-matrix. Its unique entry is the variance of $T$.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. If i got $X$ ~ $N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and I need to find distribution of Y, where $Y_1 = 2X_1 - X_2 + 4$ and $Y_2 = 3X_1 + X_2 - 3$, then how matrix A will look like? And what about the $4$ and $-3$?

Comment: Perhaps it is best you ask another question!

Comment: Then you can write $Y=AX+b$ where $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and calculate $\Sigma_Y=A\Sigma_XA^T$. Then $b=(4,-3)^T$ and does not play any part in the calculation of covariance.